# How to use hardware buttons

Tags: java, button, usb

im trying to implement a quiz for a big project.

Each team has a hardware button, as soon as the button is pressed they can answer the question.

How do i get the signal from the hardware button in java? The button is plugged in with an usb cable.

I found a lot of related questions but they never get fully explained, and im trying to understand it aswell...

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Is the button an off the shelf usb quiz button, or have you just wired a button to a usb port?

Comment: We got a button from school, it guess it will be a playstation like controller with a single button on.

Comment: You don't have it yet? Then the question can not be answered as there is no one way. Chances are if it's an off the shelf solution it will have an SDK.